# R (igraph): orientation of edge beginning and ending from same vertex

Tags: r, igraph

I want to change the orientation of the edges that start and end at the same vertex. When I use plot.igraph, these edges are all facing right, which means the vertices that are on the left side of the circle, will have their edge overlap on other edges. Does anyone know how we can control their directions, for example point to the outside of the circle? Below is the actual figure I want to edit.

[image: Example of problem]

A small example if you want to play around with is posted below:

```
library(igraph)
g <- data.frame(start=c("a","a","b","b", "c", "c"), end=c("a","b","b","c", "c", "a"))
graph <- graph.data.frame(g, directed = T)
plot(graph, layout = layout.circle(graph))
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control this with the parameter `edge.loop.angle`.
See the help page `?igraph.plotting`

```
plot(graph, layout = layout.circle(graph), 
     edge.loop.angle=c(0,0,4*pi/3,0, 2*pi/3,0))
```

[image: Graph with angled loops]

Note that you need an angle for *all* edges,  not just the loops, even though this only applies to loops. Also, it appears that the angle gives the amount of *clockwise* rotation from the horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *all* the edges have to be referenced, which made a large network hard to work with.  This seems to work:

```
edgeloopAngles <- numeric(0)
b <- 1
M <- matrixSize
m <- 0

for(row in 1:nrow(myMatrix)) {
    for(col in 1:ncol(myMatrix)) {
        if (row == col) {
            m <- m+1
        }
        if (myMatrix[row,col] > 0) {
            edgeloopAngles[[b]] <- 0

            if (row == col) {
                edgeloopAngles[[b]] <- (2 * pi * (M - m) / M)
            }
            b <- b+1
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you call the igraph, use it like this:

```
plot(g, layout=star, vertex.label.cex=0.75, vertex.label.family="sans", edge.curved = T,  vertex.size=15, edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.width=E(g)$weight, edge.loop.angle=edgeloopAngles, main="Graph Name")
```

Comment: I am trying to use this code bc I have the same exact issue. What does `matrixSize` mean here? Is this the row number of the data.frame, g, or `matrixSize = 6`? OR is this the dimensions of the data.frame, g, (6x2), so `matrixSIze = 6x2`? Also does `myMatrix` mean the data.frame (g) or the `graph` object made by passing the `graph.data.frame` command to g?  In other words, is `myMatrix = g` or is `myMatrix = graph`? I ask bc I cant get the loop you wrote to work no matter what I do. Thanks!